# Power Supply for PIC32

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, pic, microchip, current-limiting

I'm working on a PIC32 design and am looking at the power supply. Currently I have a solution in mind as below.

`12V -> MBR360G (Schottky Diode) -> MCP1584en -> 5V -> MCP1726 -> 3.3V`

But looking at some of the development boards from Microchip, they also add a current limiter like MIC2005 or similar. What is the best practice here, is this needed and what is the main purpose? Short circuit protection or more for the ability to enable power once stable? The 3.3V consumers on my board is really just the PIC itself and a very small number of low power consuming ICs.

The MCP1726 already has some level of short circuit protection, albeit maybe not as good as a MIC2005.

Hope to hear some thoughts on this.

Comment: If you've got no external connections that might get shorted I don't see any reason for the current limiter. I've designed several PCBs using pic32's and they've been in production for years without serious issues. They don't have any bus current limiters.

Comment: @Drew thanks! Ok that makes sense, using the current limiter only if you have external connections, I will proceed with that approach. Many thanks for the help!